# How to use django-registration along with django-profile?

Tags: django

https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration 
This is what I am using for user registration . Once , I log in the user is not able to get into the userprofile page .

Thus I installed this 
https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/ for user profile .

Now , this produces a conflict in urls.py and also settings.py file .

How to resolve it . What changes needs to be done with urls.py and settings.py so that , when a user logs in , he/she is redirected to the profile page .

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's some sort of Redirect To settings that you can set on your settings. Since settings file is a python file, you can do conditional settings as well.